# How can I trigger the mouse sonar (as MSDN refers to it) in Windows through code?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, input

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-mouse-input

I'm trying to make a program to control the mouse and keyboard in Windows through an Xbox One controller with Xinput.h, and I need a way to easily show where the mouse is on the screen, similar to the Windows "Mouse Sonar" feature (it puts circles around the cursor when you press CTRL).

I tried triggering the sonar with a virtual keypress using the INPUT struct, but it doesn't do anything. Is there another way to trigger the circles to show up, or is there a better way to make the circles altogether?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib") 

int main()
{
SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETMOUSESONAR, 0, (bool *) *x, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
Sleep(5000);
ZeroMemory(&input, sizeof(INPUT));
input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input.ki.wVk = VK_LCONTROL;
input.ki.dwFlags = 0; //0 for a keypress
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
Sleep(100);
input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; //this or 0x0002 for a key up
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
Sleep(100);

cout << "Done";
x[0] = false;
SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETMOUSESONAR, 0, (bool *) *x, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
return 0;
}
```

While this runs, during the Sleep(5000);, I can press CTRL on my keyboard and the circles show up (until the setting is turned off at the end of int main). But, the virtual keypress doesn't do anything. Any help?

EDIT:
Fixed the code above (it was pulled from an in-progress project, and I forgot to add some lines back in). But, it still doesn't work as I want it to (it doesn't trigger the sonar with SendInput).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

INPUT input;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESONAR, 0, (PVOID)1, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
Sleep(5000);
ZeroMemory(&input, sizeof(INPUT));
input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input.ki.wVk = VK_LCONTROL;
input.ki.dwFlags = 0; //0 for a keypress
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
Sleep(100);
input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; //this or 0x0002 for a key up
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
Sleep(100);

cout << "Done";
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESONAR, 0, (PVOID)0, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about what is your x variable but with `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESONAR, 0, (PVOID)1, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);` and `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESONAR, 0, (PVOID)0, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);` your code works fine for me I can see the sonar where the mouse is

Comment: That's not the issue, my code works in that regard. I want to trigger the sonar in code, virtually. I tried using the INPUT struct to press the CTRL key virtually, but that doesn't work. Is there another way to trigger it virtually?

Comment: Manually pressing the `CTRL` key and triggering via `SendInput` both worked fine for me. Is there anything you missed?

Comment: Did you change anything from my code in the original post? (if you did, paste your program into a comment)

Comment: I also fixed the code from my original post, check it again.

Comment: According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput):The function returns the number of events that it successfully inserted into the keyboard or mouse input stream. If the function returns zero, the input was already blocked by another thread. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.So maybe your `SendInput` failed, add error checking to your function, maybe you can find the reason.